# How to alert when specific HPA's desiredReplicas is not equal to currentReplicas

Tags: kubernetes, datadog, hpa, keda

I have kubernets setup where I am implementing KEDA solution for autoscaling. KEDA is creating HPA for autoscaling and I would like monitor this solution to see if only HPA that is spun up by KEDA is having desiredReplicas equal to currentReplicas, if not then alert in DataDog.
Any thoughts on how I can filter on HPA's that are spun up by KEDA by putting some filter in Datadog? And then checking its replicas to alert?

Comment: Do you have the option to set annotations on the created resources?

Comment: @jordanm Thank you for your response, I actually have following annotation set on the HPA ->
``` 
metadata:
  annotations:
    kubectl.kubernetes.io/last-applied-configuration: >
      {"apiVersion":"keda.sh/v1alpha1","kind":"ScaledObject"}
```

Comment: Just for the detailed information - I am trying to setup a monitor in DataDog where I am checking if HPA's current and Desired count is equal or not, and HPA should be filtered by either labels or annotations. But somehow datadog allows from filter which is only taking the scope to filter and not labels or annotations. Let me know if you know if you have any idea about this querying.

Comment: I think this is what you're looking for https://docs.datadoghq.com/containers/kubernetes/configuration?tab=datadogoperator#configure-tag-mapping

Comment: @jordanm do you mean if I set those those datadog tags with the resource label then those tags will appear in datadog monitor's `from` field?